# onClick() and AlertDialog onClick - Android Studio

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, messagebox

i am a new programmer using Android studio and I have the following in one of my activity's code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { /* code */ }

@Override
public void onClick(View ButtonSelected) 
{ 
   switch (ButtonSelected.getId())
   {
      case R.id.Button1:
      // code
      break;

      case R.id.Button2:
      // code
      break;

   }
}

public void GUIMessageBox()
{
    /* this function is called in the cases where a message box must appear
       to the user and he has to select either "Yes" or "No".
       the function initializes the AlertDialog.Builder and present it to the
       user*/

     new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Sample Title")
            .setMessage("Sample Message")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // code for Yes selection
        }
    })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // code for No selection
        }
    })
            .show();
}
```

When I run the app, the app works normally. When it is needed to present the message box I get the error "Unfortunately, App has stopped"

When i go back to my code the .setPositiveButton and .setNegativeButton look like:

```
  .setPositiveButton("Yes", (arg0, arg1) -> {

                        // code for "Yes" case
                })
```

.setNegativeButton("No", (arg0, arg1) -> {
             // code for "No" case

})

I think is because there are more than one "onClick" functions.
I tried to avoid this but still did not managed to fix it.

Does anyone have a hint for this ?

Thank you :)

Comment: crash log will be more helpful in identifying the cause

Comment: where are you calling the `GUIMessageBox`?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 the GUIMessageBox is a funtion inside the activity code .. all the above methods are included in the same activity code

Answer (score 0):

Change "this" in

> new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

to "nameClass.this" (ex. MainActivity.this) and change the "id" in both

> public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)

to "which"

```
public void GUIMessageBox()
{
    /* this function is called in the cases where a message box must appear
       to the user and he has to select either "Yes" or "No".
       the function initializes the AlertDialog.Builder and present it to the
       user*/

     new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Sample Title")
            .setMessage("Sample Message")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // code for Yes selection
        }
    })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // code for No selection
        }
    })
            .show();
}
```

That's how I have it in my code, hope it works

Comment: Just changing the parameter argument ("id" > "which") won't make any difference.

Comment: @alb thank you for your reply !  the button1 & button2 (inside the current onClick method) are normal buttons of the corresponding activity.  if i change the signiture of the onClick function from View to DialogInterface, how to i have to call the onClick function for them ?   currently I have it like this in the onCreate:    findViewById(R.id.ButtonForOption1).setOnClickListener(this);